# Executing Powershell script containing Commandlets

Tags: c#, powershell, scripting, arguments, pipeline

I need to execute Powershell script containing my custom Commandlets  ( exist in different assembly) from C#. I tried following approach but it just invokes the commandlet only once and that's it, while in the script that commandlet is written more than once.

```
Get-MyParameter myTasks

Start-Process notepad.exe

Get-MyParameter myTasks
Get-MyParameter myTasks
Get-MyParameter myTasks
```

While, MyParameter is written in different assembly.
Tried Code is :

```
var powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create();
powerShellInstance.Runspace = runSpace;

var command = new Command("Import-Module");

command.Parameters.Add("Assembly", Assembly.LoadFrom(@"..\CommandLets\bin\Debug\Commandlets.dll"));

powerShellInstance.Commands.AddCommand(command);
powerShellInstance.Invoke();

powerShellInstance.Commands.Clear();    
powerShellInstance.Commands.AddCommand(new Command("Get-MyParameter"));             

powerShellInstance.AddScript(psScript);

var result = powerShellInstance.Invoke();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the script to the same pipeline you added the `Get-MyParameter` command to. In effect, you are doing

```
get-myparameter | { … your script … }
```

Try using separate pipelines instead.

```
var result1 = powerShellInstance.AddCommand("Get-MyParameter").Invoke()
var result2 = powerShellInstance.AddScript(psScript).Invoke();
```

Also, you can simplify your module loading code to

```
powerShellInstance.AddCommand("Import-Module").
    AddParameter("Name", @"..\CommandLets\bin\Debug\Commandlets.dll")).
        Invoke();
```